# Only show today's date in CalendarView

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design, android-calendar

[image]

How do I display `CalendarView` like this without the calendar?

I don't want the calendar.

[image]

Can someone please help me I am not able to figure it out. Thank You.

Comment: If want to show the Date only then why you need CalendarView? Don't use CalenderView and simply show date.

Comment: AFAIK You need to create your own view for it . If you do not need months and year graphically then `CalendarView` is useless. Just create a view and add (+1/-1) in dayofYear.

Answer (score 0):

Try add below line in xml

```
android:calendarViewShown="false"
```

in Datepicker.

Comment: I don't think this will give the output as in question . This will open DatePicker like way back to Kitkat and below.

Comment: As @ADM mentioned it didn't work. Thank You for the help

Comment: @Satyam Rai, Yes it will applicable only in `android:datePickerMode="spinner" ` with sdk version of 21 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a TextView and set text on it like this:

```
String myFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
textView.setText(sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was not able to do it with existing component I made a custom view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="7dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/previous_date"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_previous_date_gray_24dp"
    android:onClick="previousDate"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dateText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="2015-06-18" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/next_date"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_next_day_gray_24dp"
    android:onClick="nextDate"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```